# Softmax vs ReLU in output layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a dataset with 2 classes.
By simply using SGDClassifier from sklearn, I get the perfect confusion matrix for the test data:

```
array([[1081, 0],
       [0, 982]])
```

I want to reproduce this result with a pyTorch, but remove the binary classification.
The code looks something like this:

```
class TestClassificator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.input_layer  = nn.Linear(12, 128)
        self.hidden_layer  = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(128, 2)
        self.hidden_activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.output_activation = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        #
        x = self.input_layer(inputs)
        x = self.hidden_activation(x)
        #
        x = self.hidden_layer(x)
        x = self.output_activation(x)
        #
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x
```

I want to use softmax so that the sum of all outputs is 1. In this case, the confusion matrix:

```
confusion_matrix(DataFrame(labels).values.argmax(axis=1), DataFrame(y_pred_list).values.argmax(axis=1))

array([[1072,    9],
       [0,  982]])
```

If I use a ReLU at the output, I will get perfect results again.

What's my mistake? Why does softmax work worse in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by " but remove the binary classification"?

Comment: You have a mistake in code, why did you use `x = self.output_layer(x)` after `self.output_activation(x)` there is no any type of layers after softmax, it should be the last activation function in your neural network.

Comment: @Hamzah. I plan to expand the number of data classes. (and get outputs like [0.1, 0.3, 0.5...N], n - number of classes)

Comment: Generally people don't train with `softmax` activation function in the backpropagation, it's numerically less stable / empirically doesn't train as well. Most people use log softmax instead or else (more common) use binary cross entropy loss on the logits output by the last layer